# Create a raster from polygon

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, geopandas, rasterio

I have a shapefile of thousands of polygons.
I'm looking to loop through each polygon and create a raster of the shapefiles boundaries for each polygon.
I'm looking for each raster to have the value of 1 for the areas where the polygon exists and a value of 0 where it doesn't.
I've tried the below but the rasters are off both in terms of shape and crs.

```
eco_sys = gpd.read_file(all_habitats_path)
# eco_sys = eco_sys[eco_sys.EUNIScombD == 'A6.51']

eco_len = len(eco_sys.geometry)
eco_list = [1] * eco_len
rst = rasterio.open(cropped_rast_template)
transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
    rst.crs, ENV.get("jose_crs_str"), rst.width, rst.height, *rst.bounds
)
meta = rst.meta.copy()
meta.update({
    'compress': 'lzw',
    'crs': ENV.get("jose_crs_str"),
    'transform': transform,
    'width': width,
    'height': height,
    'nodata': -999
})
# eco_sys.geometry.values[0].buffer(0)
shapes = ((geom, value)
          for geom, value in zip(eco_sys.geometry, eco_list))

with rasterio.open('data/tmp/all_habs.tif', 'w+', **meta) as out:
    out_arr = out.read(1)
# combined_rasters = None

for idx, shape in enumerate(shapes):
    print(' idx, shape : ',  idx, shape)
    if idx != 11:
        burned = features.rasterize(
            shapes=shape, fill=0, default_value=1, out=out_arr, transform=out.transform)

        with rasterio.open('data/tmp/eco_sys/'+str(idx)+'.tif', 'w+', **meta) as dst:
            reproject(
                source=burned,
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, 1),
                src_transform=rst.transform,
                src_crs=rst.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=ENV.get("jose_crs_str"),
                resampling=Resampling.nearest,
                dst_nodata=-999)
            dst.write(burned, 1)
```

Comment: Ill mark as answered once I have completed my workflow fully.

Answer (score 1):

So, a flaw in my logic.
What Ive gone about doing is creating a single raster from my shapefile.

```
eco_sys = gpd.read_file(shapefile)
eco_len = len(eco_sys.geometry)
eco_list = [1] * eco_len

# read in template raster to create raster that we'll create from our shapefiles
rst = rasterio.open(raster_template)
out_arr = rst.read(1)
meta = rst.meta.copy()
meta.update(compress='lzw')
shapes = ((geom, value)
          for geom, value in zip(eco_sys.geometry, eco_list))

with rasterio.open(output_raster, 'w+', **meta) as dst:
    burned = features.rasterize(
        shapes=shapes, fill=0, default_value=1, out=out_arr, transform=dst.transform)
    dst.write(burned, 1)
```

There are values in my file that I can now use to create the rasters that I was looking for.
So I can now copy my current rasterised shapefile and create the binary single rasters from that file depending on the values within it.

## No Solution to my problem.

I have R code that works, but in attempting to build a web app Im trying to use python. Unfortunately, though I can create the raster using rasterio it doesnt have the accuracy that I need and therefore problems propagate down the line. Im just going to have to work around that and call the R script from python for the initial rasterization.